# U ~ $N(0,1)$, V ~ $N(0,\theta)$, W ~ $N(0,1)$ are independent random variables. $X = U+V$, $Y=V+W$, find the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

U ~ $N(0,1)$, V ~ $N(0,\theta)$, W ~ $N(0,1)$ are independent random variables. $X = U+V$, $Y=V+W$, find the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.

Here both $X \& Y$ are follows from $N(0,\theta+1)$, so they have the same distribution, then can I say the joint distribution is just one of PDF of them? Or the production of PDF of them?

Comment: Nope, they're neither equal, not independent, so neither of the solutions you mentioned is correct. As a hint, note that $X$ and $Y$ are independent given $V$. Consequently, $f_{XY|V} = f_{X|V}f_{Y|V}$, and both of the terms on the right side are easy to establish. Finish off by using the total probability law.

Comment: Both $X|V\&Y|V$ follow $N(v,1)$, so $XY|V$ is bivariate normal? Then find $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XY|V}f_{V}dx$? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must prove that $X$and $Y$are independent for conclude that de joint is the multiplication of densities

Comment: Intuitively, they do independent, can I say since $U,V,W$ are independent, then even though there is same part $V$ in both $X,Y$, but the other part are still independent, so $X,Y$ are independent?

Comment: The vector T=(U,V,W) is independent. Let g,h:R^3\toR such that g(u,v,w)=u+v and h(u,v,w)=v+w. Because g and h are borel measuring, then g(T) and h(T) are independent

Comment: Sorry, I don't know measure theory, but it looks good, thanks

Comment: The condition "borel measuring" you can omit, every function that you can "see" has this condition